# Magento Product Flat Data and Catalog Search Index issue

Tags: indexing, magento-1.6

We are running Magento store having 8k products. The tow indexing is not working. Throwing some errors.

**Product Flat Data Error**

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table './bofc_magento/#sql-f22_6554c.frm' (errno: 121)' in /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(327): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2548): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

**Catalog Search Index**

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually' in /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(123): Zend_Cache_Backend->getTmpDir()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(940): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale.php(668): Zend_Locale_Data::getContent('en_US', 'date', NULL)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(763): Zend_Locale::getTranslation(NULL, 'date', Object(Zend_Locale))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(699): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getStoreDate(1, NULL)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(634): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getAttributeValue(145, NULL, 1)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(230): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_prepareProductIndex(Array, Array, 1)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(128): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(83): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

Both indexes are run from command line. I Googled both errors but did not find any suitable solutions.

Comment: If nothing has changed recently, I would check that your db server hasn't run out of diskspace.

Comment: @B00MER I have checked the disk space. It has sufficient space.

Comment: Are all of the table types `InnoDB`? I believe only one table should be `MyISAM`

Comment: Yes, All tables types are InnoDB.

Comment: Is `var/` under your magento install write/readable from the webserver? What version of Magento?  Also you can also try and simply drop the tables `catalog_product_flat_1` as the indexer will re-create it, however a full reindex will be required. `catalog_category_flat_store_1` is another table created during indexing. The search problem looks to be permissions related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651276/zend-framework-could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache-dir

Comment: Sounds very much like a combination of disk space and permissions

Comment: @sonassi I have sufficient disk space and db has appropriate permission.

Comment: @BOOMER I dropped the tables catalog_product_flat_1 and catalog_category_flat_store_1 and tried to reindex it but getting same error. Both tables are not created. I checked db user permission again. DB user has all permission except GRANT.

Answer (score 1):

Your error explains it.

You are out of disk space and your permissions are wrong.

Check your disk usage on your DB server with `df -h` and fix your permissions with [this](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/stop-magento-permissions-errors-permanently/)